# Nonlinearity of model using Sobol indices

Tags: nonlinear, sensitivity-analysis

I'm analyzing a computationally demanding numeric model where I want to show that nonlinearities play a certain role for my problem. I want to do this using Sobol sensitivity indices of first oder by showing that their sum is less than 1.

However, I am a bit unsure how to prove this, as the difference may also come from uncertainties due to the sampling in MC-simulation.

Is there anyone who has experience in this?
My first shot to tackle the problem would be that hypothesis testing can be a solution as the indices are random themselves due to sampling issues. Are there opinions on this?

Thank you in advance
Sobol

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the variance of these estimators is often large and conclusions derived from them need to be validated statistically. The problem is that the distribution of the estimators is often quite involved, and for some conclusions (such as ranking) you need the joint distribution.

But there are a variety of different estimators around. Some of them are much better (in certain cases) than others. Check out the excellent R-package [sensitivity](https://rdrr.io/cran/sensitivity/) by Ioos et. al. It contains about a dozen different estimators (including references to the original papers)  with variance estimates. For many methods, they also provide bootstrap procedures. From this, you should be able to construct confidence intervals and hypothesis tests.

Of course, since this is basically "just" Monte Carlo, all other remedies to reduce variance of Monte Carlo estimates apply as well. I.e. increase sample size, quasi-random numbers or specific designs like Latin hypercubes and such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

However, I got still one question in mind that is of great importance to me.
Is Hypothesis testing the right way to check if the difference bettween the estimators and one comes from nonlinearity?
So I can add up the variances I found out for the different variables and do hypothesis testing (one-sided test for the mean) using the results?